# Unable to use retrofit android library getting error while compiling

Tags: android, performance, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using the below code to call the API. I have added custom key that wont work:

```
 String API_BASE_URL="http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?  api_key=adfasdfasd/";

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    MoviesApi service = retrofit.create(MoviesApi.class);
    Call<List<Pictures>> Pics = service.listPictures();
```

I have added below dependencies for retrofit in gradle:

```
   compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.1'
   compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
```

This is my interface

```
   public interface MoviesApi {
     @GET("results")
     Call<List<Pictures>> listPictures();
   }
```

I'm getting:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseUrl must end in /: http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=adfasdfasd/ at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Retrofit.java:496)
>                                                                                   at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Retrofit.java:439)
>                                                                                   at com.example.varunbehl.mymovies.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5459) 
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

I have added / at the end of BASE URL. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the method of passing your URL:

You should pass the URL like below:

**String API_BASE_URL="http://api.themoviedb.org/3/;**

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
MoviesApi service = retrofit.create(MoviesApi.class);
Call<List<Pictures>> Pics = service.listPictures();
```

And your interface would be like this:

```
     public interface MoviesApi {
     @GET("/movie/popular?{api_key}/results")
     Response getMovieList(@Path("api_key") String api_key, Callback<Response> callback);
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Is Response your custom class?

Comment: no it's from the okhttp package but you can also get a response in model class like you have declared in your code.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the base URL literally had to be "http://api.themoviedb.org". It couldn't have any segments and parameters after the domain.

Then you can define endpoints:

```
public interface MoviesApi {
   @GET("/3/movie/popular?api_key=adfasdfasd/")
   Call<List<Pictures>> listPictures(@Query("api_key") String api_key);
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would double check the API documentation and be sure that you have the correct format for your query.

http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/#reference/discover/discovermovie/get

They have the popular movies as show below:

http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=*YOUR API KEY GOES HERE*

I would recommenced having the base url:

.baseurl(http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie)

Then appending your query parameters.

Comment: Retrofit doesnt supprt the complete url or is it just standard?

Answer (score 0):

```
 String API_BASE_URL="http://api.themoviedb.org/";

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
MoviesApi service = retrofit.create(MoviesApi.class);
Call<List<Pictures>> Pics = service.listPictures();

public interface MoviesApi {
 @GET("/3/movie/popular")
 Call<List<Pictures>> listPictures(@Query("api_key")String api_key);
}
```

Comment: interface is it missing something , It says identifier or type expected

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is your base URL having a query parameter in it. So when trying to use retrofit in the way you have it set up, the route you have defined would be like this

```
http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=adfasdfasd/results
```

This is not a valid structure for your URLs, as query parameters must be the last part of it.

It is also good practice to use the highest-level URL without any actual routes as your BASE_URL, so
in order to make this work, you might try something like this:

```
String API_BASE_URL="http://api.themoviedb.org/3/";
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
MoviesApi service = retrofit.create(MoviesApi.class);
Call<List<Pictures>> Pics = service.listPictures();
```

And then your interface would look like this:

```
public interface MoviesApi {
   @GET("movie/popular/results")
   Call<List<Pictures>> listPictures(@Query("api_key") String api_key);
```

}

You may also want to verify that your routes are in fact correct. You wont get a proper response from the API if you have the routes in your interface defined incorrectly.

Comment: Why is there a comma after  Call<List<Pictures>> listPictures(@Query("api_key") String api_key ,

Comment: Do I need to append api key over there ?

Comment: The comma was just a typo. I have updated it to remove that. You api_key will get passed in when, in your activity, you call your "listPictures" method with your api key as the "api_key" parameter.